# Retrofit 2 error URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to call a legacy API using Retrofit 2, this is the URL `"/api/0.3/v3/?endpoint=/admin/customers/6728382/addresses.json"` and this is the interface method

```
@GET("/api/0.3/v3/?endpoint=/admin/customers/{customerId}/addresses.json")
Single<GetCustomerAddressesResponse> getUserAddresses(@Path("customerId") String customerId);
```

However I am getting this error,

> "URL query string
>   "endpoint=//admin/customers/{customerId}/addresses.json" must not have
>   replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query."

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think `id` has to be `int` type. Try to change `String` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

> "URL query string "endpoint=//admin/customers/{customerId}/addresses.json" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query."

As it suggests you should use `@Query` instead of `@Path`.

```
Single<GetCustomerAddressesResponse> getUserAddresses(@Query("customerId") String customerId);
```

You may like to read this in details about `@Query` annotation https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html

Comment: It says that it want a query however the url I am supposed to hit accepts customerid in path param.

Comment: I think you need to change a URL a bit in your code `/api/0.3/v3/?endpoint=/admin/customers/6728382/addresses.json` to `/api/0.3/v3/admin/{customerId}/addresses.json` then try with `@Path` if you use ? then you have to use `@Query` annotation after ?.